No me funcionan algunas propiedades de css, ¿Alguien podria explicarme la razon porfavor?
Intento hacer un proyecto tipo css y necesito la propiedad margin para continuar y me sale como si no estuviera en el visual:(
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: 'Poppins'
}

Eso pongo y me detecta como si en realidad esas propiedades no existieran, los errores salen después la primera llave que es esto {}


No entiendo el error, puede agregar una imagen?

Ya la agregue, la verdad es que eso me pasa por momento y no se la razon

Será que querías aplicar ese estilo sobre todos los elementos? En ese caso, te faltó usar * como selector.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

El error no está en las propiedades, debes utilizar un selector para decirle a css cuál elemento es el que lleva esas propiedades. Ej:
/*   ↓ Falta eso   */
    div {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       font-family: 'Poppins'
    } 

